# Typescript: How to index a nested object by key?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an object:

```
export const light_theme = Object.freeze({
  colors: {
    brand: {
      primary: COLORS.ROSE_500,
      secondary: COLORS.BLACK_50,
      background: COLORS.WHITE,
    },
    button: {
      action: COLORS.RED_500,
      action_hover: COLORS.RED_600,
      interactive: COLORS.OCEAN_500,
      interactive_hover: COLORS.DARK_OCEAN,
      neutral: COLORS.WHITE,
      disabled: COLORS.GREY_300,
    },
  }
});
```

I'm trying to create an object to loop through all the values of the object:

```
export const LightTheme = () => (
  <div>
    {Object.keys(light_theme.colors).map((type) => (
      <TypeContainer key={type}>
        <TypeTitle>{startCase(type)}</TypeTitle>
        <ColorTable>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <NameTh>Name</NameTh>
              <ValueTh>Value</ValueTh>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {Object.keys(
              light_theme.colors[type as keyof typeof light_theme.colors]
            ).map((color_name) => (
              <ColorRow key={color_name}>
                <CodeTd>
                  <Code>
                    theme.{type}.{color_name}
                  </Code>
                </CodeTd>
                <td>
                  <ColorDemoContainer>
                    <ColorBox color={light_theme.colors[type][color_name]} />
                    <ColorValue>
                      {light_theme.colors[type][color_name]}
                    </ColorValue>
                  </ColorDemoContainer>
                </td>
              </ColorRow>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </ColorTable>
        <Divider />
      </TypeContainer>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

However, Typescript keeps complaining that the type is incompatible

[image]

How can I type it?

Comment: Where `type` is declared in the first lambda, type it like `type: keyof typeof light_theme.colors`. Same idea for the lambda with color_name.

Comment: Or turn off the no implicit any rule.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there's a reason for the `Object.keys` to be defined as a function returning `string[]`, but as workaround you can re-declare it like this:

```js
declare var Object: Omit<ObjectConstructor, 'keys'> & {
    keys<T extends Record<string, any>>(o: T): (keyof T)[]
}
```

[TS Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=39&ssc=2&pln=37&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoAEyTQBsUi40IA7AZ3gGEB5AGW4QBlAFyIa0SgB4OUYCwDmAGjgy58gHwVqdBkiasOcACoBPMEk6sYKOUiijk6GADoAYpy016jZu3inzI2AYWiQHYhd3Tx0fAy4IWmgjFAAjUPCnNw8qL119PzgAORQQJCMACwyMLOjvPV9DADUUWgBXMsqxTKicmPq4uEtqI0oqyOztOvzDIbCu6p7JvIb4xKgAESQQCEsWa1t7efHa5YHLNYAhCAAPMazJAG9yOBf9NdFVBXIAX01eqZWgwS0GabTmjgWE1ysQKHAYME4KDYcwAFDAzHNPvIAJRwAC86hUMFkChOMJmwKgCAgAHc7otof0CutgAA3YDUQ4Q47kciA2jAeTlGAAfRg5S2ejxcG4KQAVjQXNgkEgAF5IFFPV5vaBsURa7WvFJQFAsUZwA2Gw1gWQgBgmUQ8fhCZwIbiCACiIoArAAGX2KZ5Ww3I3yUe2OvgCQTOC68ACCnAA0j6A0Hg0b0ABreQ4VpmyPOmMAdQAEgBJIwewMZ7414MpVowGCsfXpjNwJzAVuDKMuhAe9aptMd15d1gi8oQVl2QvR12DkUANn99dHchgdi7M7nLu4nA98cKw7XHY3W4wbKQk+ns97Rec63jCBT+8PhVPGZYSCbJtou5LCsq0-YNKGANhUlCc0nXnABxAcAE0RQAZlXdttTrdtvh+bEKH+PJWQYGV5UVURuBAYJJFlBUMF2GRWgwaBlHwLMkBMNh8EJAAyC121Y9jJCMOAkGuTczTYMRmCgKQsWUU0THUdQUQgUQjGxUQUX4iBMGMbEAG0AF0fl5QFeEFYUKklfE4BRXECRs9tJDA1l1HQ14HmoxVnH4tgUQFIVRXFSVnGYNY2GxZw7TAFE0QxOzCRRNyrUEjFdn2b8oDgfi8QedFzF+JKOxSwJglCdQHjhWBEWRWLzGxb5JAAegCMpSqQVzR2S84kkg9rCs6uBJCClBKA6gbOqGqAxvG8bJGKUoKnUeakCa5bFv6mbDUkUF2kWnaVsa-b1s2orGuJaaTsGs6JRGi6TqGlIIEoBSNpmjySOqHzEsuzr-OFMUJVKELKTYPS8qQIyfqtCKopi0LoBFFgSiQeKHKhoruqpWksrYnL4agRHkYK9GBskWYRjuknRzJp6+qpn6gqB3KMW+ZwHnxwnSmw+nZsa2ZKZ5l4mvJ0bXpJobRcFibMc2bY0psDKBal4MacuG4dSgHK-sCwGkGBsKwYxAy9I5pHSgM744EapXla2zH9pt23gwebWAeC-HQfB43TeRi2xdt4XKQd-36cDtZZZ2KwFbsR2qaamBJeVsPoGpGlY-G7F6pD5Kzse570+1ZOoGSNI6c2yQWXZTkrfTpqWvlg4lcz7nXia5zXNw8ggA)